# Correlation between two signals with two different sizes

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the correlation between two signals, where it returns 1 if both are the same and it will return between 0 and 1 otherwise. The problem that the two signals have different sizes so resampling is needed. I already did it but the output is not correct. Can anyone help me to implement it in an efficient way.

My code:

```
MaxRow = max(size(A,1),size(B,1));
MaxCol = max(size(A,2),size(B,2));
NewA = resample(A,MaxRow,size(A,1));
NewB = resample(B,MaxRow,size(B,1));
NewA = resample(NewA',MaxCol,size(A,2))';
NewB = resample(NewB',MaxCol,size(B,2))';
for s = 1:MaxRow
    a = NewA(s,:);
    b = NewB(s,:);
    c(s)=real(corr(a',b'));
end
c(isnan(c)) = 0 ;
score = mean(c);
```

Comment: What do your variables `A` and `B` contain?  You could use `interp1` for resampling.

Comment: it contains the sample points of signal A and B (vector)

Comment: @SMH corr ignores if there's a constant bias (y intercept) or scale. Do you care if there's a constant offset/scale or not?

Comment: I do care if there is

Comment: ok how do you penalize it if there is. Are you looking for MSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a toy example.

```
% Example Data
x = 0:9;
y = 1:0.1:10;

% Check if y is longer
if length(x) < length(y)
    x = interp1( x, linspace( 1, length(x), length(y) ) );   % Resample x
else
    y = interp1( y, linspace( 1, length(y), length(x) ) );   % Resample y
end

% Get corrcoeff
c = abs( corrcoef( x, y ) );   % Corrcoeff solution here
c = c(2,1);

% Get MSE
m = mse( x - y );   % MSE solution here
```

`linespace` will generate indicies between `1` and `length(x)` with `length(y)` number of divisions.

Essentially `interp1` will resample the variable to the length of the other one. The if statement will check which one needs resampling. The function `corrcoef` will get the correlation coefficient of the coefficient of the 2 signals. Since `corrcoef` is between 0 and 1, we need an absolute value. If you don't care about scaling and bias `corrcoef` will work for you.

If you plan to use `MSE` instead, then you can use the `MSE` function on the error `(x-y)` but it will not be between 0 and 1. Any comparison method will work with this resampling code.

Comment: your solution is not  working as the two vectors dont have the same size.

Comment: @SMH Sorry please try again. I should have used linspace

Comment: It is still not working as x and y have different size. same error

Comment: @SMH What error do you get? Can you run my code without errors?

Comment: 10  c = abs( corrcoef( x, y ) );   % Corrcoeff solution here
Error using corrcoef (line 83)
The lengths of X and Y must match.

Comment: @SMH Is this using your data or mine? I edited my answer 2 hours ago btw, you might want to re-copy and paste it.

Comment: using my data. also when I use yours it gives me a matrix not a single value.

Comment: @SMH well the corrcoef is in the first element. I edited my answer to get 1 number. Can you post your data so I can test?

Comment: it is hundreds of sample points, but why you selected index 1,1 .. it is always one

Comment: @SMH Sorry off diagonals, it was one of them XD I'm fine with hundreds of sample points if it will help reproduce the issue for me. Perhaps you have it as a column matrix instead of a row matrix? If so, just transpose it.